# What is the structure of "To do, that is ..."

Tags: grammar, pronouns, inversion, cleft-constructions

> Henry David Thoreau:
>
> To affect the quality of the day, that is the
> highest of arts.

What is the structure of this sentence?

I think it's safe to simplify to "To do, that is A".

Is it a cleft sentence? Is it an inversion?

Can I change "that" to "this", or "it"?

Would the normal order be "A is to do"?

**Edit:**

My question focus on an infinitive before the main clause, and the subject of the main clause is "that".

I also found "**to be or not to be, that is the question**". This quote so happens to also use "that"? Are there any hidden rules?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Your link discusses a noun phrase ahead of the main clause. Mine is an infinitive and the subject is "that". Which answer in your link answers my question?

Comment: The antecedent (referent) of "that" is "to affect the quality of the day". Therefore, the infinitive phrase functions as a nominal phrase (or clause, if you prefer to call it that). It is thus analogous to "John" or "Mary" in the linked question.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan What you said could make sense. If "To do, that is A" is not a fixed phrase, is "Doing, this/it is A" correct as well?

Comment: I think so, if you mean something like: "Doing homework, that is boring."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost two centuries ago, in a different written dialect (now extinct), Thoreau wrote:

> - *To affect the quality of the day, that is the highest of arts.*

Today we might write

- ***It** is the highest of arts to affect the quality of the day.*

in something like the equivalent written register. That sentence is an extraposition from

- *To affect the quality of the day is the highest of arts.*

with an infinitive subject. Extraposition moves heavy subject clauses to the end of the sentence and inserts a dummy ***it*** to pretend it's the subject.

Thoreau, however, was emphasizing the infinitive, and he used *that* (no doubt with a heavy stress, though that isn't represented in English writing) to refer back to the infinitive. So in effect, the structure was an apposition, like a left dislocation:

- *Ale, that's the stuff!*

It isn't a cleft, and it isn't an inversion. It's just a poetic mode of emphasis.

Comment: Frankly, I can totally see two tipsy professors chatting in a bar where one might say to the other: "To flunk a lazy student, that is truly a pleasure. Sláinte".

Comment: Awesome response. Would you shed light on in which dialect book is written, or give some references?

Comment: It was what passed for literary English two centuries ago, in the New England part of the United States. The language and its literature have changed since Thoreau and Emerson.